# Change value displayed to User in Slider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

Basically I want to change the text inside of the value. In this example I want to change the 41 to say '41°'.

Comment: Can you please add the code here. Also, the npm module you are using for the slider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs https://material-ui.com/api/slider/#main-content

> **valueLabelFormat**
>
> The format function the value label's value. When a function is
> provided, it should have the following signature:
>
> - {number} value The value label's value to format - {number} index The value label's index to format

So, Just add `valueLabelFormat={valuetext}`

Answer (score 2):

According to Material-UI documentation, you should use ValueLabelComponent attribute.

Create a functional component:

```
function ValueLabelComponent(props) {
  const { children, open, value } = props;

  return (
    <Tooltip open={open} enterTouchDelay={0} placement="top" title={`${value}`C}>
      {children}
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

And then assign it:

```
<Slider
  ValueLabelComponent={ValueLabelComponent}
/>
```

Comment: This is more useful when you want to show a custom component and not only change the format of the text